# How to draw a panel background before its components

Tags: java

I'd like to use my Graphics2D object to draw some lines and rectangles on the background of my JFrame's ContentPane, but super.paint(g) completely repaints the panel afterwards, and putting the drawing code after it just puts it on top of the existing components.

How can I draw the panel then my custom drawing code then the components?

Comment: Why not add a panel to the frame and override its `paintComponent` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFrame is a Swing component so you should be overriding paintComponent() rather than paint().

Comment: Well this is awkward... I'll try that then report back

Comment: OK, I changed all of my components to Swing components and changed all the paint() methods to paintComponent() methods to see if that would simplify things, and it just made each component draw the other ones inside itself...